# Node.js Mongoose Login with bcrypt

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, bcrypt

So, I'm creating a login functionality using Mongoose with Node.js. Where I'm getting error while inserting wrong password.

**Here is the error which I'm getting in response:**

*status: 0,
msgCode: 421,
message: error,
responseData: {}*

I don't know why but I'm not getting proper error for Wrong Password situation which is

*status: 0,
msgCode: 420,
message: 'Invalid credentials',
responseData: {}*

**Here is my code :**

**Controller :**

```
module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
    var user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };
    var rules = {
        email: 'required|email',
        password: 'required' 
    };

  Validator(user, rules, {}, (err, status) => {
    if (!status) {
        res.json({
            status: 0,
            msgCode: 412,
            message: 'Validation failed',
            responseData: err
        });
    } else {
        userModel.login(user).then(dbResponse => {
            if (dbResponse.email != null) {
                jwt.sign(user, key.secret, { expiresIn: 600000 }, (error, token) => {
                    if (error) {
                        res.json({
                            status: 0,
                            msgCode: 418,
                            message: error,
                            responseData: {}
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        res.status(200).json({
                            status: 1,
                            message: 'Login successful',
                            responseData: { token: token, userData: dbResponse }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                res.json({
                    status: 0,
                    msgCode: 420,
                    message: 'Invalid credentials',
                    responseData: {}
                });
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            res.json({
                status: 0,
                msgCode: 421,
                message: error,
                responseData: {}
            });
        });
    }
  });
}
```

**Model :**

```
module.exports.login = (user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userModel.findOne({ email: user.email }, (error, row) => {
        if (row) {
            if ( bcrypt.compareSync(user.password, row.password) ) {
                resolve(row);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: And.... your question is what?! Where should we help you?

Comment: @Marc actually when I insert wrong credentials I want to get following response --> 
 status: 0, msgCode: 420, message: 'Invalid credentials', responseData: {} in both cases where email is wrong, and when password is wrong. So, when I'm reject using promise, controller catch error and gives me following response -->  status: 0, msgCode: 421, message: error, responseData: {}

Answer (score 1):

As the [answer from Lzok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69887891/9990990) already said, because you reject the promise if the password mismatch in the `userModel.login(user)` function, the catch block will be always executed and the execution will never reach the `res.json` statement with msgCode 420

The fast solution is to modify the `login` function like this:

```js
module.exports.login = (user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userModel.findOne({ email: user.email }, (error, row) => {
        if (row) {
            if ( bcrypt.compareSync(user.password, row.password) ) {
                resolve(row);
            } else {
                resolve({ email: null });
            }
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

But it would be better to resolve with an `undefined`:

```js
module.exports.login = (user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    userModel.findOne({ email: user.email }, (error, row) => {
        if (row) {
            if ( bcrypt.compareSync(user.password, row.password) ) {
                resolve(row);
            } else {
                resolve(undefined);
            }
        } else {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

And to update your if statement in the `then` block:

```js
            if (dbResponse !== undefined && dbResponse.email !== null) {
                jwt.sign(user, key.secret, { expiresIn: 600000 }, (error, token) => {
                    if (error) {
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because this line `userModel.login(user).then(...).catch(...)` is catching the error from the `login` method of your model. It does not matter which reject, both are captured in this catch.
Maybe you can use a type error there and check it in the original catch, something like:

```js
userModel.login(user).then(...).catch((error) => {
    if (error.type === 'invalid_credentials') {
        res.json({
            status: 0,
            msgCode: 420,
            message: 'Invalid credentials',
            responseData: {}
        });
    }
    
    // Maybe another handles you want here. Or return the default error
    res.json({
        status: 0,
        msgCode: 421,
        message: error,
        responseData: {}
    });
});
```